# Using Spring Devtools with -parameters flag

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Java 8 Reflection API's Parameter-class in my Spring Boot app, so I need to compile my source code with -parameters flag to get names of parameters and not just arg0, arg1... Now I'd like to use Spring Devtools to make my development process much faster. But how to tell Devtools compile Java classes also with -parameters flag, cause now it loses real parameter names and try to use arg0, arg1 etc...

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the IDE you are using.

As explained in the [Spring Devtools Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart):

> Applications that use spring-boot-devtools automatically restart
>   whenever files on the classpath change.

So it's up to you to compile your Java files with the compiler arguments you need.

---

### Eclipse

Go to the **Preferences** and check the option:

**Java** > **Compiler** > **Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection)**
[image]

---

### IntelliJ

Go to the **Settings** and then add `-parameters` to the field:

**Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Compiler** > **Java Compiler** > **Additional command line parameters**
[image]

---